# Single fql query for "friend id" to display latest photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am looking for optimized FQL way getting latest photos per user_id, the only one I can think now is to get aid's (album id's) and query each aid for photos ... (this is lots of querying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery, should be like so:

```
SELECT object_id, src_small
FROM photo
WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me())
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
```

hope this helps